# Am failing to publish my xamarin mobile app using visual studio 2019

Tags: json, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

When  i try to create archive i receiving this error message. 'The archiving process has failed. Please see the Errors Section for more details' The section referred to giving the following error '...The archiving process has failed. Please see the Errors Section for more details'

Comment: Can you show the details about the error message? And did you try to update the visual studio 2019 to visual studio 2022?

Comment: Thank you i have managed to do by ticking 'Use Incremental Android Packaging System'